# WWDG IRQHandler although WWDG disabled, sprintf fail - postponed

Tags: infinite-loop, irq

I'm trying to use STMF411RE and its UART, SPI and EXT_INT.
Of course, I am trying to solve my problem using google, but nothing I've found yet.

However, SW looks after wireless NRF24L01+ module. This module has SPI interface to read, write registers (like sent, received payload ... settings) and one IRQ pin. This PIN is asserted if packet is sent, received or re-transmitting fails.

My code contents from a few files, so I won't publish it here whole.

So, I have two STMs, one as TX another as RX of meantioned rf modules. I wrote my own 'library' for those rf modules.

Whole system works, that RX (TX) is appropriately set and waits for interrupt. If interrupt pin is asserted, device is asked via DMA-SPI for content of STATUS register and according to this value is evaluated if was something received (successfuly sent) or only max attempt number reached.

If was something received I send this using DMA-UART to Termite terminal to see it.

```
int main(void)
{
nrf24l01plusTypeDef prx;
uint8_t address_5byte[5] = "ADR01";
uint8_t rxpld[33]; memset(rxpld, '\0', 33);

HAL_CLK_TIM_SPI_GPIO_UART_DMA_INIT();
//HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim3);
DEACTIVE_CHIPSELECT_0();

nrf24l01_init_PRX(&prx, address_5byte);
nrf24l01_set(&prx);

while(1){

    if((nrf24l01_rf_receive(rxpld)) == PACKET_RECEIVED) {

        uart_tx_flag = 0;
        sprintf((char*)rxpld, "%s\n", rxpld);
        HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart1, rxpld, 33);
        while(!uart_tx_flag);
    }
}
}
```

On the TX side all works fine. I send incremented value, always filled to the 32bytes by '0' if is needed. Like this:

```
This gonna work this gonna run !
00000000000000000000000000000001
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
00000000000000000000000000000153
00000000000000000000000000000154
```

But receiver always stops after 154 cycles of trans-receiving (1x per 500ms I send cycle) and throws this:

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
WWDG_IRQHandler () at ..\startup/startup_stm32f411xe.s:127
127   b  Infinite_Loop
```

and is in infinit loop:

```
 * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor receives an 
 *         unexpected interrupt.  This simply enters an infinite loop, 
   preserving
 *         the system state for examination by a debugger.
 * @param  None     
 * @retval None       
 */
  .section  .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
   Default_Handler:
   Infinite_Loop:
   b  Infinite_Loop
   .size  Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler
```

Please, how to solve this ? Note that WWDG seems disabled by project-create wizard

[Here is not-enabled WWDG in mxcube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUw4o.png)

Comment: I found out it falls, when value 00~00155 is passed to sprintf, why ?